# Trigger a property changed event from outside of code behind (partial class)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have written a simple UI using WPF/XAML and successfully used the iNotifyPropertyChanged method to update some values.... Hooray!

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Margin=" 1" Text="{Binding DeviceType, StringFormat=0, Mode=OneWay}" FontFamily="Nexa"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Margin= "1" Text="{Binding DeviceSerial, StringFormat=0, Mode=OneWay}" FontFamily="Nexa"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Margin=" 1" Text="{Binding DeviceName, StringFormat=0, Mode=OneWay}"  FontFamily="Nexa"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" Margin=" 1" Text="{Binding DeviceBatteryLevel, StringFormat=0, Mode=OneWay}"  FontFamily="Nexa"/>
```

The code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public InstrumentViewModel Instrument = new InstrumentViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

        DataContext = Instrument;    

        var collection = new PortableDeviceCollection();

        collection.Refresh();

        foreach (var device in collection)
        {
            device.Connect();

            if (device.DeviceModel == "Instrument Test Platform")
            {

                Instrument.DeviceType = device.DeviceModel;
                Instrument.DeviceSerial = device.DeviceSerialNumber;
                Instrument.DeviceName = device.FriendlyName;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

This works absolutely fine. However, I'd like to use a timer to poll for devices. When I do this, and try to use the INotifyPropertyChanged method from the timer event, the properties within my Instrument Class are being updated- but the XAML bindings are not being set.

I am trying:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public InstrumentViewModel Instrument = new InstrumentViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

        DataContext = Instrument;    

        Timer intervalTimer = new Timer(5000);
        intervalTimer.Enabled = true;
        intervalTimer.AutoReset = true;
        intervalTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        InstrumentViewModel Instrument = new InstrumentViewModel();

        var collection = new PortableDeviceCollection();

        collection.Refresh();

        foreach (var device in collection)
        {
            device.Connect();

            if (device.DeviceModel == "Instrument Test Platform")
            {

                Instrument.DeviceType = device.DeviceModel;
                Instrument.DeviceSerial = device.DeviceSerialNumber;
                Instrument.DeviceName = device.FriendlyName;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I am missing some fundamental here, but I was assuming that the method for OnTimedEvent, being within the MainWindow Class, would still be able to access the DataBinding from the XAML code.

Is this to do with where I am setting the 
`DataContext = Instrument;` ?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You are just creating an `InstrumentViewModel` instance in your _OnTimedEvent_ method and assign it to a **local variable**, but outside of this method, **nothing** is using this instance. So, of course you don't see anything happen, because this `InstrumentViewModel` instance exists only within that method and ceases to exists when the method returns.

Comment: There is nothing in the collection so what are you looping over? The binding will not work if you change the thing you're binding to (not properties of the thing but the thing itself).

Comment: So just remove the first line from the OnTimedEvent method.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, From the explanation given in the question (with regard to the 1st working example), one can assume that `PortableDeviceCollection.Refresh()` will populate the collection...

Comment: Note that you declare a local variable named `Instrument` in your _OnTimedEvent_ method. A local variable will take precedence over any field/property of the same name. Thus, when you are using the "Instrument" identifier in your _OnTimedEvent_ method, the method is actually working just with the local variable named _Instrument_, it is NOT working with the field _Instrument_.

Comment: @elgonzo The working example works because `DataContext = Instrument` and then `Instrument` properties are updated. To be honest, I don't even know how that is working because there is nothing in the collection so execution will never reach the inside of the loop.

Comment: Thanks to all for your input. I have passed the instance of the view model to the OnTimedEvent, as suggest by @elgonzo. This now appears to update as expected - many thanks.

Comment: One more thing, if you create a new _InstrumentViewModel_ instance (as you are currently attempting in the OnTimedEvent method) instead of using the existing one in the DataContext, you will have to assign the new _InstrumentViewModel_ to the DataContext (and not just to the Instrument field). Otherwise, the DataContext will still refer to the old InstrumentViewModel instance and not to the new one you created. But then again, why would you want to create a new _InstrumentViewModel_  instance instead of using the existing one in the DataContext?